# How do I verify this hash app is safe to give it permissions to access notifications?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, notifications

This is the only app on notifications list which doesn't have a name and appears with a hash. I'm afraid it is a spyware or malware.

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows 10 Mobile are you running? Are you enrolled in the Windows Insider programme, and if so, which ring? Does this app show up in the all apps list? If you tap-and-hold on it and select "Rate and review", it should take you to the app's Store page. Searching for the GUID returns no definitive results, but other people seem to have the same issue, especially after upgrading from WP8.1 to W10M, with the most common suggestion being to do a hard reset.

Comment: I'm on the final public build 10.0.14393.448. I'm not a member of Windows Insider program. The app doesn't appear in all apps list, I only find it in notifications. So tap and hold isn't available for this hash app from notifications section in which I define how I receive notification from each app.